# Text is not showing up

Tags: html, css, text

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvwWo.png
I'm trying to get text to show up in the yellow box. But I cant figure out why It's not working.

This is the code im using. It's only in the yellow box It's not working.

```
 <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="Main">
  <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Startsida</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Medlemmar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galleri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
     </ul>
  <div id="Start">Textytexttext</div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>



@charset "utf-8";

#Header {
    background-color: #F00;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}


#Main {
    background-color: #0C0;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
#Start {
    background-color: #FF0;
    width: 990px;
    height: 690px;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(46px,auto,auto,10px);
}
#Footer {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 20px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with this style `clip: rect(46px,auto,auto,10px);` If you delete it the text appears. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DNq5A/).

Answer (score 0):

It's the line `clip: rect(46px,auto,auto,10px);` that is doing it. Why are you using it? I'm sure there is another way to do it without using this.

Edit: Just seen Barry beat me to it.